# Line Integral calculating the ds

Tags: line-integrals

Doesn't change the result, but why in the last steps constant in front of the integral is 9 and not 27? Where did the 9 that came from squaring the dx/dt and dy/dt go?[image]

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying, the function is $xy$. Yes it is incorrect.

Comment: @MathLover the part of the integrand outside the square root has a constant of 9, and the square root contributes a constant of 3, giving a total constant of 27

Comment: @SamFreedman yes noticed the function later. I think they knew the answer was zero and so got sloppy :)

Comment: @MathLover Yes you're right. Besides, $9 \cdot 0 = 27 \cdot 0$ so after the fact they weren't even wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They forgot it. The first line of step 4 should have been:

$$\text{Area} = \int_{t = 0}^{t = \pi} (3 \sin(t))(3 \cos(t)) \sqrt{(-3\sin(t))^2 + (3\cos(t))^2} $$